# Moq - set async task to throw

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I've slimmed down some code I'm trying to test to the example below

I've followed the advice I found online and carried out the setup below.

My problem is when the test runs it never returns from the Task.WhenAll

I'm confined to .net 4.5.2 so don't have Task.FromException at my disposal.

The code that calls the dependency is:

```
    public async Task<int> CountCustomFields(bool onlyVisible)
    {
        var countClientCustomField = clientService.CountCustomFieldsAsync(onlyVisible);
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(countClientCustomField);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // some loggging etc
        }
        finally
        {
            // some tidy up & set the result
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Mocking is configured in the following test method:

```
    [Test]
    public void WhenAsyncMethodThrows_WeShouldCatchTheException()
    {
        mockClientService.Setup(x => x.CountCustomFieldsAsync(It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Returns(new Task<int>(() => { throw new Exception("err"); }));

        Assert.DoesNotThrowAsync(() => sut.CountCustomFields(true));
    }
```

I'm updating the example to include the dependency mentioned in the comments. I think it can be ignored that this is a microservice. In fact it could be any dependency which returns a Task

```
public interface IClientService
{
    Task<int> CountCustomFieldsAsync(bool onlyVisible);
}
```

Comment: What is `clientsClient`?

Comment: Its a webapi microservice

Comment: That doesn't help us debug it - you have a Task that is apparently hanging but you haven't included any of the code relevant to the class/method that returns that task.

Comment: @AntP `CountCustomFieldsAsync` is the action getting *mocked* it's implementation is irrelevant

Comment: I'm not sure its correct to say its hanging. But it is not returning and throwing an exception like I believe my setup has instructed it to

Comment: yes, i haven't made that clear as i haven't shown it being created but mockService is a new Mock<IClientService>

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos really? I don't see it getting mocked anywhere.

Comment: @AntP `mockService.Setup(x => x.CountCustomFieldsAsync(It.IsAny<bool>()))` ???

Comment: Ok. So that's mockService. What about clientService?

Comment: I've updated. It could have been clearer

Comment: I can't believe it, I started writing an answer then found out I already answered this 2 years ago!. According to my smarter self, Moq 4.2 has a `ThrowsAsync` method. You can write : `.Setup(...).ThrowsAsync(new InvalidOperationException());`

Comment: @user48408 the question was clear from the start to people that use Moq - how can you set up a `Task` method to throw? You also tagged the question with `moq` and even added `Moq` to the title. You couldn't make it any clearer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it wasn't clear at all. The member that is mocked and the member that is called are *different members*. Sure we could assume that's a typo but I don't think you can exclude silly errors like that when the question is explicitly about code that doesn't work.

Comment: That was it, so simple..i've done it many times before, don't know why i thought it was more complicated. I can't accept answer in comments if you want to add a response to question i can

Comment: @AntP `CountCustomFieldsAsync` is mocked *and* called. What are you talking about?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos clientService != mockedService.

Comment: @user48408 I already did - that duplicate is mine. I answered the same question almost exactly 3 years and 10 days ago, even updated it for later versions and forgot about it

Comment: @AntP if you want to argue, you can argue that you can't define a controller action inside a test class. It's obvious that one part of the code is the action, the other is the test

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no idea what you're talking about - there are two different references and only one of them has a mocked member. The question was about code that doesn't work. Mocking a method on the wrong object was an entirely valid line of inquiry. You clearly didn't read the question properly before you (curtly) shot down my comment.

Comment: @AntP you can vote to reopen